# disabling button on click stop form from submitting

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to disable a button after a user clicks it. I have this functionality working great but now the form wont submit... Here is my javascript:

```
<script>
  $('.button').on('click', function(event) {
    $(this).prop('disabled', true);
  });
</script>
```

Again this disables the button nicely but now my form wont submit. Is this a well known problem?

Comment: I cannot replicate this: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/2zo6uev5/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Click` event occurs before form `submit` and `disabled` button prevents submission. This is workaround:

```
<script>
  $('.button').on('click', function(event) {
    $this=$(this);
    setTimeout(function(){$this.prop('disabled', true);},50);
  });
</script>
```

Another workaround is to process `$('form').on('submit',function(){...});`

Edit: ...INSTEAD.

Comment: Not only does that sound weird, it seems to not be the case: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/2zo6uev5/

Comment: @ChrisG Your fiddle is disabling form submission by returning false from the event handler.

Comment: @Barmar ...yeah, but the `onsubmit` event is *not* cancelled at all. And if you remove the line or return `false`, the form submits just fine. Unless I'm completely off-track, disabling a button does not in any way prevent a form submission, and why on earth should it?

Comment: @ChrisG I'm not getting the alert in your fiddle.

Comment: @ChrisG alert in your fiddle doesn't appear ;(

Comment: It does on Firefox, but indeed not on Chrome. What the hell?

Comment: @ChrisG See the first line of my answer ;)

Comment: @AlexKudryashev I saw it, I just never noticed that Chrome prevents the submission if the button is disabled. And since Firefox behaves differently, your first line is true for Chrome but not in general.

Comment: @ChrisG I agree, not in general. But workaround works "in general"

Answer (score 5):

Instead of putting it in the `click` handler, put it in the form's `submit` handler.

```js
$('form').on('submit', function(event) {
  $(this).find(".button").prop('disabled', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <button class="button">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: This is cool but how can I still pass the button value params to the controller?

Comment: @Bitwise See Variant 1 of my answer

Comment: @Bitwise Looks like this has the same problem as Vitali's answer. I guess the timeout method is the only real solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
  $('.button').on('click', function(event) {
    $(this).prop('disabled', true);
    $(this).parents('form').submit();
  });
</script>
```

Comment: This is pretty good, but the button value won't be included in the form parameters.

Comment: So change places of event lines. At first:
 $(this).parents('form').submit(); Then $(this).prop('disabled', true);

Comment: It doesn't matter where you place it. When you call `submit()` from code, it doesn't send any buttons. Buttons are only sent automatically when the submission is triggered directly from clicking a submit button.

Comment: You right. Add timeout to second event's line: setTimeout(function(){ $(this).prop('disabled', true); }, 100);

Comment: Or use **<input type="submit">** instead of **<button>Submit</button>**